# doClick on an invisible button

Tags: swing, jbutton, actionlistener

Can I call `doClick` on a button after making it invisible.
like:

```
StopBtn.setVisible( false );
StopBtn.doClick();
```

will `doClick()` still do its work?

Comment: I think this is one of those instances where it is best to try it out for yourself and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tried it for you. It still works, which means it still triggers the `actionPerformed()` method.

However, it doesn't work if you disable it: `button.setEnabled(false)` which makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Dan for trying it for me.  Yes, it makes sense when it doesn't do anything when it is disabled.but it's weird if doClick() still works even if button is invisible.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to discover this was of course to just test it (e.g. in a unit test if you fear those guys at Oracle would ever change the behavior)

```
@Test
public void clickOnInvisibleButton(){
  JButton button = new JButton( "test button" );
  button.setVisible( false );
  final boolean[] buttonClicked = new boolean[]{false};
  button.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
      buttonClicked[0] = true;
    }  
  });
  button.doClick();
  assertTrue( "Button has not been clicked", buttonClicked[0] );
}
```

Otherwise, you could have taken a look at the source code of that method

```
public void doClick(int pressTime) {
    Dimension size = getSize();
    model.setArmed(true);
    model.setPressed(true);
    paintImmediately(new Rectangle(0,0, size.width, size.height));
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(pressTime);
    } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
    }
    model.setPressed(false);
    model.setArmed(false);
}
```

There you do not find a check on the visibility. Looking a bit further (e.g. in the `setPressed` method of the model), you will find the check for the `enabled` state, but clearly see that there is no check for the visibility present. You also see that an `ActionEvent` is fired, which will trigger the `actionPerformed` method of the button

```
public void setPressed(boolean b) {
    if((isPressed() == b) || !isEnabled()) {
        return;
    }

    if (b) {
        stateMask |= PRESSED;
    } else {
        stateMask &= ~PRESSED;
    }

    if(!isPressed() && isArmed()) {
        int modifiers = 0;
        AWTEvent currentEvent = EventQueue.getCurrentEvent();
        if (currentEvent instanceof InputEvent) {
            modifiers = ((InputEvent)currentEvent).getModifiers();
        } else if (currentEvent instanceof ActionEvent) {
            modifiers = ((ActionEvent)currentEvent).getModifiers();
        }
        fireActionPerformed(
            new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED,
                            getActionCommand(),
                            EventQueue.getMostRecentEventTime(),
                            modifiers));
    }

    fireStateChanged();
}
```